# Difference in Order of insertion when inserted data using Union and Union all

Tags: sql-server, union, difference, union-all

Recently i noticed a behavior in inserting into table using Union and Union All Statements.

```
declare @table1 table(id varchar(MAX))

insert into @table1
    select 'B'
    union all
    select 'A'
    union all
    select 'C'

Select * from @table1
```

output is:

id

---

B

A

C

```
declare @table2 table(id VARCHAR(MAX))

insert into @table2
    select 'B'
    union
    select 'A'
    union 
    select 'C'

Select * from @table2
```

output is

id

---

A

B

C

Please tell why this behavior.?

Is Union will do an 'Order by' before inserting.?

Comment: We have to specify `Order By` in  `SQL` query for ordered set. If we don't specify `Order By` then there is no guarantee that returned set will be ordered one.

Comment: What you see is that the DBMS has to sort records in order to detect duplicates and possibly remove them. Obviously this leads to storing the records in a different physical order. But as BhatiaAshish mentioned: data in a table is considered unordered. What you are seeing is temporary and can change every minute (due to database reorganisation, more or less work load, an index added or removed, ...). If you want an ordered result use `ORDER BY` in your query. Else you get the records in an arbitrary order.

Answer (score 2):

We have to specify `Order By` in `SQL` query for ordered set. If we don't specify `Order By` then there is no guarantee that returned set will be ordered one. Please check below syntax -

```
declare @table1 table(id varchar(MAX))

insert into @table1
    select 'B'
    union all
    select 'A'
    union all
    select 'C'
    --Order by 1 /* Order by during insert don't make sense, we have to specify order by in final select */

Select * from @table1 Order by id

declare @table2 table(id VARCHAR(MAX))

insert into @table2
    select 'B'
    union
    select 'A'
    union 
    select 'C'
    --Order by 1

Select * from @table2 Order by id
```

And there is difference between `Union` and `Union All` i.e., `Union All` return all rows without looking into duplicate values but `Union` has to check duplicate values.

Comment: the `ORDER BY` should be in the `SELECT` statement. It doesn't make sense to have it in the `INSERT` statement, unless you have an identity column in the table

Answer (score 1):

`UNION` causes a distinct collection of values (no duplicates)

`UNION ALL` causes a non-distinct collection of values (including duplicates)

As an implementation artifact, SQL Server uses sorting to make the duplicate suppression more efficient in the `UNION` case.

Where you do not stipulate an `ORDER BY` cause, you have no right to expect any specific order. The DBMS can `INSERT` or `SELECT` these records in any way that is convenient. It may even change its implementation between versions, or depending on what data is immediately available in its cache or sorted by some other index etc.

**TL;DR:** If you care at all about order, you must stipulate ORDER BY